# set width to 100% with rCharts and slidy?

Tags: r, rcharts

Is it possible to dynamically adjust the with on rcharts?

Right now I have

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "my name"
output:
  slidy_presentation:
    incremental: yes
---

## Slide with rCharts

```{r, comment = NA, results = "asis", tidy = F, echo=F}
library(rCharts)
hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, type = "multiBarChart")
n1$set(width = 1024)
n1$show('iframesrc', cdn = TRUE)
```
````

I tried `n1$set(width = 100%)` but that does not work

Answer (score 0):

I believe in rCharts you can only set width and height in pixels (px).

```
library(rCharts)
hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, type = "multiBarChart", width = 1024)
n1$show('iframesrc', cdn = TRUE)
```

I personally manually change it in the html document.